# In Laravel eloquent, how to get "No query results for model" for a "Belongs to" relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, belongs-to

**Background:**

I have two models, Attribute and Value, which is one-to-many relationships.

```
class Attribute extends Model
{    
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Models\Value::class);
    }
}


class Value extends Model
{    
    public function attribute()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Models\Attribute::class);
    }
}
```

In the database, below are the only records:

```
attributes
    id           name
    3            xxxx
    4            yyyy

values
   id      attribute_id     value
    1           3             ooo
    2           4             ppp
    4           3             qqq
```

In the api.php

Route::get('attribute/{attribute}/values/{value}', 'ValueController@show');

In the Controller:

```
public function show(Models\Attribute $attribute, Models\Value $value)
{
    $value = $attribute->attributeValues->find($value);

    return $value;
}
```

**Situations:**

- Situation 1:  For request `{{url}}/attribute/3/values/1`, of course, I can get the correct object;
- Situation 2: For request `{{url}}/attribute/3/values/2`, I got empty response with code 200;
- Situation 3: For request `{{url}}/attribute/3/values/3`, I got error of `No query results for model [App\\Models\\Value].` with code 404;
- Situation 4: For request `{{url}}/attribute/100/values/1`, I got error of `No query results for model [App\\Models\\Attribute].` with code 404.

**Question**:

Obviously, the situation 3&4 give the correct response but the situation2 do not. My question is how to make the situation 2 response with similar error and with the code of 404.

Seems the `No query results for model` happen before the controller. What is the process to trigger it happen?

Many thanks!

Comment: So my question is basically, how to make Laravel eloquent to recognise the associated relationship.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?